# Kotlin Android base method not call

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a base activity like this which has abstract method abc()

```
abstract class Base: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        Log.i("abc", "onCreate base")
        abc()
    }

    abstract fun abc()
}
```

MainActiviy extends Base

```
class MainActivity : Base() {
    override fun abc() {
        Log.i("abc", "method called from base")
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var mainPresenter: MainPresenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.i("abc", "onCreate")

        App.appComponent.plus(MainModule(this)).inject(this)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            mainPresenter.performToast(editText.text.toString())
        }
    }

    fun showToast(string: String) {
        toast(string)
    }
}
```

When I run MainActivity, the log only show "onCreate". It means that the onCreate from Base was not called. Can you tell me why the base method is not called?
It looks silly but I try and the base was not called
The same code works in JAVA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not overriding the same `onCreate` method in those two classes. Looking at the documentation it seems one or the other will be called depending on if `persistableMode` is set to `persistAcrossReboots`. This means the code in your `Base` class probably never gets executed regardless of what you do in the subclass.

Comment: Could you please edit my code. I thought I call it by super.onCreate()

Comment: Use either `onCreate(Bundle)` or `onCreate(Bundle,PersistableBundle)`, do not use both. I don't know what your intended use is so I can't give you the 'correct' answer.

Comment: This solved a totally unrelated issue I had for using the "wrong" `onCreate` signature